# Blower motor not blowing

Tags: chevrolet, hvac, equinox

I have a 2006 Chevy Equinox and the blower motor will not blow at all. I replaced the blower motor and it would blow intermittently for a few days then stopped all together so I then replaced the blower motor resistor and I still have nothing. I need help!!!

Comment: Have you checked the wiring to the motor with a voltmeter to be sure there's voltage reaching the motor during these times of failure? Maybe there's an intermittent in the cable/connector or controlling hardware.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I've checked all fuses and relays even the connection behind the kick panel on the driver's side and have power to all except the blower motor and resistor. I was hoping there was something I could do that might be a bit less painful than tracing wires down lol

Comment: Last I saw ('99 Cavalier), Chevy blowers had a 'speed control module' - a little circuit board with some (surface-mount?) resistors on it.  The tracks on the PCB would sometimes crack.  Usually (for me, anyway) this would cause one or more speed settings to fail; but, I could imagine it might fail intermittently before going total.  IIRC, it was under the passenger's-side dash.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your fuses for a loose connection? On and off performance suggests it's something loose somewhere. Try following the wiring as best you can to see if you can find any shaky parts. If you have a multimeter you can use it to check your fuses continuity and also check if the wiring is providing any power to the motor.

Comment: Yes I've checked all that so I guess I have a hot date with some wires haha

Comment: Yeah I don't have a multimeter or know how to really use one even if I had one. I guess I'll be tracing down wires lol